# Nested structure crashing upon receiving input

Tags: c, nested, scanf

I've got two structures, one of which is nested into the other (Date into Video). I've got other functions that insert data into arrayVideo[0].id/title/producer just fine. However once I try to input something for arrayVideo[0].releasedate.Year/month/day it just crashes the program. No warnings during build or anything. Have I implemented the nested structure incorrectly? I have been tinkering with it for awhile now.

```
typedef struct Date
{
  unsigned int Day;
  unsigned int Month;
  unsigned int Year;
} Date;

typedef struct Video
{
  unsigned int id;
  char title[90];
  char producer[60];
  Date releaseDate;
} Video;

//Global array
Video arrayVideo[6];

int main()
{
printf("Please enter the release YEAR of the video:\n");
scanf("%u", arrayVideo[0].releaseDate.Year);
}
```

Comment: If you compile the code with the flag `-Wall` you'd have seen a warning about passing a value rather than a pointer to `scanf`. Definitely use that flag while debugging code.

Comment: Where can I add these flags?

Comment: It depends on your compiler.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using `gcc` you can compile using `gcc -Wall -o <executable name> <filename.c>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
scanf("%u", &(arrayVideo[0].releaseDate.Year));
```

You're giving it the value, not the pointer.